# DataGridTextColumn namespace found in silverlight MainPage xaml code behind, but not found in silverlight library

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, datagridtextcolumn

I'm successfully using DataGridTextColumn in a silverlightapp main page code behind.

This works:

```
using System.Windows.Controls; 
namespace myNamespace
{
    public partial class MainPage
    {
        <snip>
        private DataGridTextColumn CreateTextColumn(...)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            <snip>
        }
    }
}
```

I want to move the method to a static class in a silverlight library

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace myNamespace
{
    public static class DataGridBuilder
    {

        private static DataGridTextColumn CreateTextColumn(...)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
        }
     }
}
```

Intellisense is not seeing a definition for DataGridTextColumn, and it won't compile either.  I have a reference to System.Windows.Controls in both projects.  MSDN says I have the right namespace.  What am I missing?  NOTE: class name light blue coloring in non-working code section is put there by StackOverflow, not intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembly is `System.Windows.Controls.Data` while the namespace is `System.Windows.Controls`.

Do you have a reference to `System.Windows.Controls.Data`?

Comment: Knew it would be something simple.  Sometimes you look at something and just can't really see it.  Thanks!